# what is the path format of a file created by upload file in grails

Tags: file, grails, filepath

how to upload file in resource folder in and access that file in groovy project. I will need the absulate path - [image]

Answer (score 0):

> how to upload file in resource folder in and access that file in
> groovy project.

`src/main/resources/` is a directory that generally only exists in your development environment, not the runtime environment.  It wouldn't really make sense to write code to upload to that directory.